# How can I change Network mode between 4G and 3G in the App.?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, networking

I keep tried to change Network mode between 4G and 3G in the App.
but it fails all the time.
My last trial for this is about those setting:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.NETWORK_PREFERENCE, 0);
```

But I think it fixed with network_preference in lowercase.
Is there anybody had solve this problem?

Comment: Add your language/framework tag in the question, else, nobody would find the question! What code is written, which language, edit that in the tag of your question.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Actually this was my first question. So I didn'

Comment: Think of that. Thanks @Am_I_Helpful